# помогите написать ассемблерную вставку правильно в цикле? язык Си

Tags: c, ассемблер

Пытался написать вставку но она не заработала.
В комментарии указано то, что по идее должна делать вставка.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
     setlocale (0, "");
double x, mo, s;
int n, i;

double *X = &x;
double *MO = &mo;
double *S = &s;
int *N = &n;
int *I = &i;

printf("Vvedite kolichestvo chisel v massive \n");
printf("n:");
if (scanf("%d", &n))
{
double a[n];
double *A = &a[i];
mo=0;
printf("Vvedite znacheniya elementov \n");
for (i = 0; i<n; i++) 
  {
    printf("a[%d] = ", i);
    if (!(scanf("%lf", &a[i])))
    {
    printf("Error. Vvedeni nepravelnie dannie\n");
    break;
    }
    
    else
    {
    //mo=mo+a[i];
    asm
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"
        "mov ax, [%1] \n\t"
        "mov bx, [%2] \n\t"
        "add ax, bx \n\t"
        "mov [%0], ax \n\t"
        : "=r"(MO)
        : "r"(MO), "r"(A[I])
        : "%ax", "%bx"
    );
    if (i==(n-1))
    {
        printf("Mat ogidanie: %lf\n", mo);
        s=mo/n;
        printf("Srednekvadratichnoe otklonenie: %lf\n", s); 
    }
    }
  }
}
else printf("Error. Vvedeni nepravelnie dannie\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Команда `add` предназначена для суммирования регистров общего назначения и работает с ними как с целыми числами (а Вы передаёте указатель на `double`). Используйте FPU или SSE для работы с вещественными

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае есть два варианта

---

*Первый*

Вместо `double` использовать `float` и спокойно использовать набор команд сопроцессора x87:

```
__asm__(
    "FLDS %1 \n" // mo
    "FADDS %2 \n" // mo + a[i]
    "FSTPS %0 \n" // mo
    : "=m"(mo)
    : "m"(mo), "m"(a[i])
    : );
```

*Второй*

Использовать набор инструкций SSE, что ощутимо больнее. Делать это через асм-вставку крайне не рекомендую, можно просто через си.